# Multiple Exact word Match with Faster Processing Time in R

Tags: r

I need to do a multiple exact word match in R. Please check my code,

```
lapply(test1, function(x) length(which(grepl("\\b17.02\\b", x) |  grepl("\\b18.1\\b", x))))
```

Please help me for the code with faster processing time for this purpose.

I have generated a dataset for testing purpose,

```
x1 <- runif(n = 50000000, min = 1, max = 100)
x2 <- runif(n = 50000000, min = 5, max = 30)
x3 <- runif(n = 50000000, min = 12, max = 30)

df <- cbind.data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
```

Thanks,
SJB

Comment: remove the spaces: `"\\b17.02\\b|\\b18.1\\b"`

Comment: @missuse Thanks for your reply. In the meantime, i figured out a solution for multiple word match. So i have edited my question - To get code with faster processing time.

Comment: could you create a dummy data set for this purpose? its blazing fast on anything I tried.

Comment: This probably isn't where the speed issue is, but `length(which(x.logical))` is the same as  `sum(x.logical)`

Comment: @missuse I have generated a dataset, Please check my updated question

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for your reply. I wanted to check if a regex code or rcpp code could do the job faster.